# How to use IMA SDK to play pre-roll video ads with MPMoviePlayerController in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, ios8.1

I am working in iOS app in swift language. I need to implement google pre-roll video ads in my app and I am implement to play video with MPMoviePlayerController.So i can play DFP pre-roll video ad with MPMoviePlayerController.How to implement IMA SDK with MPMoviePlayerController in swift. 
Please provide some example and any other option to play DFP pre-roll ads video withOut IMA SDK

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlplay];
moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updatePlaybackProgressFromTimer:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tap.delegate = self;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[moviePlayerController.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(Exit:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playstart:) name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(Statechange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(LoadFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

[moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,568, [AppDelegate sharedInstance].widht, [AppDelegate sharedInstance].height);
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                      delay:0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[AppDelegate sharedInstance].widht, [AppDelegate sharedInstance].height)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
                 }];

moviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayerController.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

[moviePlayerController play];
```